# Escpaing issue with 'Not a valid choice' in Django Rest Framework

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model with a status field that looks something like this:

```
PENDING = 'pending'
DONE = 'done'
CANCELED = 'canceled'

class Event:
    EVENT_STATUSES = [(1, PENDING), (2, DONE), (3, CANCELED)]
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=EVENT_STATUSES, default=PENDING)
```

I have a serializer:

```
class EventUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('status')
```

And when it is called with the following JSON:

```
{
    "status": "done"
}
```

I get the response:

```
{
  "status": [
    "\"done\" is not a valid choice."
  ]
}
```

I think the problem is the escaping of done, but why? And how do I prevent it?

(I have a content-type application/json header).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you are making them as  1,2,3 it will store the 1,2,3 in Database.
that's why you are getting error.

You can either try with 1,2,3 (that means you will have to send 1,2 or 3 for it to be a valid choice ) or store them as correct values in the DB/Model